# PhpStorm 9 configuration

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, mamp, mamp-pro

Every time when I'm trying to debug my PHP file on PhpStorm, I got a message informed me that the PHP Interpreter is not configured. Although  I tried to configure it from `Languages and Frameworks` by adding the PHP version, but PhpStorm doesn't detect any PHP version.

First of all, I installed the XAMPP and PhpStorm together, then I deleted the XAMPP and replaced with MAMP, also I copied all my PHP files to `"htdocs"`, but this won't gave me any solution.

What is the best way to avoid this kind of problems?

Comment: just point to the php executable

Comment: I pointed, still won't detect the path of PHP version

Comment: show me what you put

Comment: Just I opened from language and framework then ==> PHP ==>PHP excutablle to pick the path of PHP version ==> but not any result

Comment: what is your OS

Comment: My current Operating system is MAC OS

Comment: 1) Please provide screenshot of how you configured PHP Interpreter 2) It's possible that your PHP installation just outputs info in a slightly different format or thing like that -- it will be better if you try the latest version (2016.3.2 right now) as there were some improvements in this area since your v9 (which is almost 2 years old now)

Comment: -@LazuOne  I've  already installed the last version of Phpstorm (2016.3.2 ), so I was wrong when I'd mentioned that the Phpstorm version was 9). Please tell me how could I post a screenshot in a comment?